# Positioning text after multiple images

Tags: graphics, positioning

I am placing 4 images one below the other. I want text to follow the images. However, text is coming after 1st image and before 2nd.

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{image1.png}\\
    \caption{caption1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{image2.png}\\
    \caption{caption2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{image3.png}\\
    \caption{caption3}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{image4.png}\\
    \caption{caption4}
\end{figure}

<Text>
```

This is the preamble.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{color}   %May be necessary if you want to color links
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,matrix,positioning}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Edit: This is an MWE that illustrates the problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Test}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{figure}[htp!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}\\
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}\\
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}\\
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}\\
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

This is the output.
[image]

Comment: Can you also provide your preamble, since your example is working for me as you expect using only `\usepackage{graphicx}`

Comment: Do not use `figure` environment if you want to force the positioning of the figures. However in this case you can use a single `figure` environment. Probably you will solve the problem in this way.

Comment: @Excelsior preamble added.

Comment: @Ivan single figure environment (without any other modification) pushes images to end of document.

Comment: @Arvind Even with your preamble it is working. Maybe you have to define the dimensions of your pictures (width or height)?

Comment: It is never a good to rely on a fixed placement of figures. It is better to always refer to the figures (you're missing `\label`'s after your captions) and then the the figures float as to use the paper most effeciently. Also never use `[!h]` it does not do what you think. Might be better using `[!htp]`

Comment: @Excelsior I solved the problem using \newpage after the figures. It works for now. We'll see if any problem arises afterwards. Thanks.

Comment: You should put all the figures into a _single_  `figure` if you want them to stay together, also never use `[!h]` (it usually warns that it is wrong (better to use `[htp]` unless you need to restrict the floats from being top of a page

Answer (score 1):

This is really a comment but it is much too long for that. It would have been really helpful if you had provided an MWE that actually showed your problem.

I have taken what code you did provide and cobbled together an MWE from it. I had no idea what `image1.png` etc., produced so I used the generally available `example-image` instead. I haven't wasted time stripping out the 16 or so packages that have nothing to do with the placement of floats and text.

```
% figprob.tex  SE 588058
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{color}   %May be necessary if you want to color links
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,matrix,positioning}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
%    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{image1.png}\\
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image}\\
    \caption{caption1}
\vspace{\baselineskip}
%\end{figure}

%\begin{figure}[h!]
%    \centering
%    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{image2.png}\\
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image}\\
    \caption{caption2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
%    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{image3.png}\\
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image}\\
    \caption{caption3}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
%    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{image4.png}\\
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image}\\
    \caption{caption4}
\end{figure}

<Text>

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

It did not show the result you were complaining about.

[image]

I did not change your `{figure}[h!]` but please pay serious attention to the commentators who said not to use `[h!]`.

Comment: I added an MWE. I changed the scale from .2 to .4 for the example image because that is closer to the size of images I'm using.

Comment: Please add an image of the output you are getting in your system when you compile your last MWE.

Comment: @SimonDispa Added image.

Comment: Please see my answer. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what is your problem:

- Why do you have four consecutive floats `figure`?
- Why you like to have each figure in own row when there is sufficient space to put two figures in one row?
- Why your figures hasn't captions?

If you have four consecutive floats, than is expected that some text after that floats can appear between floats if some of them is pushed to the next page. To prevent this, you need to have all images in one float (as is suggested in comments below your question and in nice @Peter Wilson's answer (+1) ).

One more example, how you can do this in case, that the size of images in `figure` is a bit bigger that obtained by `\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}` is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Test}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{figure}[htp!]
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} XX @{}}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{Image 1}
\label{fig:1} 
    &   \includegraphics{example-image}
        \caption{Image 2}
        \label{fig:2}       \\
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{Image 3}
\label{fig:3}
    &   \includegraphics{example-image}
        \caption{Image 4}
        \label{fig:4}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]
See figures \ref{fig:1}, \ref{fig:2}, \ref{fig:3}  and \ref{fig:4}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 1. If I put all of them in single figure environment, they are pushed to the bottom of the document.
2. Open to the idea.
3. MWE did not include captions because they are irrelevant to the problem, and I want the option of removing captions from my image.

Regarding your suggestion, is it impossible to keep your layout and vary the scale of the images (all images with same scale) while retaining neat alignment?

Comment: @Arvind, sorry, it is not clear what is your problem. Please edit your question and explain in more detail what the problem is and the desired goal. If you not need captions, just delete them from code.

Comment: I do want a solution with captions if possible. I used the h! environment because the captions can be made in a certain format: "Figure" without a figure number being displayed. If the h! has to be deleted for the solution, we have to ensure that I still have my caption format. I think I was mistaken that captions are completely irrelevant to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

With your last MWE I get three images in the first page plus some text.

[image: b]

Because the last image will not fit in the first page LaTeX moves it to the second page and fill the space with the text. To get what you want add a `\clearpage` (to clear the floats) after the third figure. (or put it after the second in your system).

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Test}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{figure}[htp!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}\\
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}\\
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}\\
\end{figure}
\clearpage % <<<< added
\begin{figure}[htp!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}\\
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```